# Installing sample products in a extension using data setup

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am developing an extension (Magento EE 1.14.1.0) in which I have the standard data setup script to

- create a website, store group and store
- create categories for the new store
- create products under the categories

When products are being created, I get the following error - Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreIds() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 257

On researching I was able to find that the problem when occurs when Status attribute is being saved. This attribute has as Website scope and the system is trying to assign the attribute to all stores under the website I created. But there is a logic in getStore function that returns a default store (with just the store id and code set - and the website not being set - which I think is a bug) when the installation process is not complete (which the system determines based on the creation date of local.xml file). So there are 2 issues:

- getStore function returns the default store (with store_id = 1) even if object being saved has a different store_id provided if the install process is still running; so how do we install products during the data setup process
- getDefaultStore does not set website_id when creating a default store (just sets the store id and code)

This issue does not occur when I keep the module disabled and then later on enable it after setup is complete.

I want to keep the extension enabled by default and have a clean install first time - is there a work around or is the approach flawed?

Comment: FYI I've got the same problem for a regular module set up script on an installed version of Magento EE 1.14.2.1